# How to set up a delegate from the child class?

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

Things are working but I’m trying to improve on how they work ;)

Here’s my scenario:

I have a custom Button and the tap event is triggering a custom function in the ViewController. This is happening via a delegate and everything is working fine.

I’m using storyboards and control+click to create the outlet to the custom button, and then setting up the delegate inside the ViewController class, like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButtonInstance: MyButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButtonInstance.delegate = self
}
```

My question:

Is there a way to set up this delegation from inside the custom button class? I saw that in Swift there isn't a self.parent, and that's what I've been looking for:

(pseudo code)

```
on custom button initialization:
 self.delegate = self.parent
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to archive but what I can say is that swift does not use the parent concept but superclasses, so you can use self.superclass. Hope that help

Comment: Anyclass can act as delegate for you...just make sure you provide the correct object instead of self and implement protocol methods there

Comment: Hello Icaro and Anish, that's not I was having problem with. But thanks anyway for trying to help me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to get a reference to the controller from inside the button to set him as delegate!?

Your `UIButton` is part of the view hierarchy - your ViewController however is not. There is not and further more **should not** be an easy way for an element of the View-part of an application to access its Controller-part. It should only communicate with the Controller through said delegate. Anything else would conflict with the MVC design pattern.

In a logical term it although does not make sense to assign someone else to be a delegate for you. It should always be the delegate initiating the delegation process via assigning itself as delegate.

Comment: Yes, you got the question right. Thanks for your MVC lesson ;) I won't try to do it anymore!

Comment: I'll have lots of custom buttons inside a specific view. So, my current plan now is from the ViewController, to loop through the view that contains all the custom buttons and assign self (the ViewController) as their delegate. This should be ok ;)

Comment: If you set them up via the InterfaceBuilder you can set the viewController as delegate as well.